# Making an array from lists of different sizes and filling the gaps with Nan in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let's say I have a list of lists, and they can have different sizes:

```
arr=list([[0. , 1.5, 3. , 0. , 1.5],[0. , 1.5, 3. ],[0., 1.33, 2.67, 4. ]])
```

I want to make this array numpy compatible and make a filled array based on the maximum length and fill the gaps with Nan:

```
arr_filled=list([[0. , 1.5, 3. , 0. , 1.5],[0. , 1.5, 3.,None,None ],[0., 1.33, 2.67, 4.,None ]])
```

My current method is to find the length of each list by `map(len, arr)` and then looping over lists and adding `None` until they all have the same size. Is there a faster and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Well, you could initialize a numpy array of Beans then just fill it in row by row. That would be faster. If you need something even faster, use numba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

arr = [[0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 0.0, 1.5], [0.0, 1.5, 3.0], [0.0, 1.33, 2.67, 4.0]]

arr_filled = [list(tpl) for tpl in zip(*zip_longest(*arr))]
print(arr_filled)
```

Prints:

```
[[0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 0.0, 1.5], [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, None, None], [0.0, 1.33, 2.67, 4.0, None]]
```

Comment: Thanks! The power of experience is obvious here from a user with 154K reputation!